# Use UML2 4.0.0 metamodel in Acceleo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, eclipse-emf, acceleo

I need to use on acceleo UML2 4.0.0 as metamodel for my source model.

Unfortunatelly, launching the acceleo code raise this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$1DiagnosticWrappedException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri 'http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/4.0.0/UML' not found. (file:/C:/Users/eclipse-workspace/exportsModels/src/model1/MyModel.uml, 3, 83)
```

I was able to use UML2 4.0.0 with ATL, but not acceleo. It seems that I have this package on the EMF Registry "Runtime Version", but not "Development Time Version", and it might be the problem.

I know how to use a metamodel owned by my workspace in acceleo, but I can't manage to find an UML2 4.0.0 metamodel. I have found an old UML2 4.0.0 plugin, but it don't work either when I installed it (https://archive.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/uml2/downloads/drops/4.0.0/R201206040919/).

Maybe having the "Extender SDK Developer Resources" plugin might work, but I didn't find a version older than 2020-12, with UML2 5.1 (https://download.eclipse.org/staging/2020-12/reports/download.eclipse.org/staging/2020-12/index/org.eclipse.uml2.sdk.source.feature.jar_5.5.1.v20200302-1312.html).

A big thanks for your help in advance,

Answer (score 0):

EMF is saying it cannot find the metamodel registered against URI 'http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/4.0.0/UML'.

If you have installed Eclipse UML with the right version, the UML2 EPackage should be registered against that URI. Is your program being ran as part of an Eclipse application that deploys the UML2 plugin? If your program is a regular Java one, you probably need to call something like UMLPackage.eINSTANCE so that the registration happens automagically.

Otherwise, I would recommend running your program in debug mode, and checking out the contents of EMF's EPackage registry.